# Exporting raw Hausdorff distance data from Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

I have been experimenting with Meshlab lately. In particular, the Hausdorff distance tool to measure distances between two 3D meshes. From what I understand about the software, is that the output of the Hausdorff distance tool is a colour heat map to demonstrate the differences. Is there any way to export this as raw data for post processing?

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the layer it creates as a .ply file, when it brings up the options uncheck the one for "binary encoding", this gives you the vertices in a space delimited file - the distances will be the quality or color:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 1576162
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha
property float quality
element face 0
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
0.6049601 5.65379 58.57785 -1.80271 -5.003513 -3.300911 0 255 240 255 0.03676568 
0.5626873 5.658148 58.56089 3.839464 -3.147465 -2.965386 0 255 17 255 0.02583417 
1.632807 5.769152 58.22455 5.618994 -0.841545 0.009307206 255 25 0 255 0.001270742
```